# How to create an elasticsearch bool query with php client

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I need to run one ES bool query which is looks something like this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "column1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "column1.raw",
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "time": {
                  "gt": "2015-02-19 00:00:00",
                  "lt": "2015-02-20 00:00:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "column1.raw": "value1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "column1.raw": "value2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have done the things upto should and now need to formulate terms part. As it is having the same index value multiple times , how can I formulate the array for it ?

I am using the following PHP code now :

```
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $termFIlter = array(
                "term" => array(
                    "column1.raw" => $term
                )
            );
        }

        $options['body']['query'] = array(
            "filtered" => array(
                "filter" => array(
                    "bool" => array(
                        "must" => array(
                            "range" => array(
                                "time" => array(
                                    "gt" => $start,
                                    "lt" => $end
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        "should" => $termFIlter
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

take this example please change fields name.set what are fields your are using .

```
$options = array(
   'fields' => array('title', 'content', 'profile_id', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'date', 'url'),
   'from' => 0,
   'size' => 10,
   'query' => array(
      ($type ?
          array(
              'bool' => array(
                  'must' => array(
                      array('term' => array('_all' => $term)),
                      array('term' => array('type' => $type))
                   )
              )
          ) :
            array('match' => array('_all' => $term))
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: But I need to have the term thing multiple times in the should section for specifying multiple values.

Comment: Can you please specify the $term variable and how you are formulating it ?

Comment: no I am not using anything. I hope you have seen the code that I have added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In [elasticsearch php client documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html) this is how you handle needing to put multiple index values of match:

```
$params = [
'index' => 'my_index',
'type' => 'my_type',
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                [ 'match' => [ 'testField' => 'abc' ] ],
                [ 'match' => [ 'testField2' => 'xyz' ] ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

So I think it would be the same for your query but with term. So like you showed in your edit or like this:

```
        $options['body']['query'] = array(
        "filtered" => array(
            "filter" => array(
                "bool" => array(
                    "must" => array(
                        "range" => array(
                            "time" => array(
                                "gt" => $start,
                                "lt" => $end
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    "should" => [
                        [
                            "term" => [
                                "column1.raw" => "value1"
                            ]
                        ],
                         [
                            "term" => [
                                "column1.raw" => "value2"
                            ]
                        ]    
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
```